# Merge some shopping cart and online store related tags

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There are many shopping related tags, a few of them could be synonymized or cleaned up:

- [cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cart) should be made a synonym of [shopping-cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping-cart).
- [acts-as-shopping-cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/acts-as-shopping-cart) is a ruby gem, so the tag wiki should reflect that.
- Merge [shop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shop), [shopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shopping), [online-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/online-store) and [webshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webshop).
- Burninate [shop-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shop-script), as it's useless. [cheeseshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cheeseshop) seems to be another name for pypy, so could be synonymized.
- Posibly others ?

Your thoughts ?

Comment: Downvoters.. Just curious as to why ?

Comment: Based on Andy's answer, probably lack of research into the tags. [Voting on Meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: Is there some subtle difference between [tag:cart] and [tag:shopping-cart]?

Comment: [tag:shop-script] is gone now

Answer (score 4):

[acts_as_shopping_cart](https://github.com/crowdint/acts_as_shopping_cart) is a ruby gem, the wiki should be updated to reflect that.

[cheeseshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPN3KTtrnZM) == pypi, so should be synonymized.